# How to pass a function name in unit testing?

Tags: c++

I am developing a library that is based a lot around the concept of Linear algebra. Because of this, I build the development suite up in stages within my spare time. One of the problems that I am encountering is testing the code and the output that I should get.

I have 10 test cases (for example), which goes like this:

```
template<typename T>
void testDiag(T begin, T end)
{
    // run test here and check 
}
```

What I really want is a way (I don't know if this is possible) to have a class "TEST_CASE" and to be able to initialise all of the tests and then have one final way to run all of the tests BUT pass in the function.

Something like this:

```
class TEST_CASE : public ClassX
{
     public:
           template<typename T> 
           TEST_CASE(T begin, T end, FUNCTION_NAME, EXPECTED_OUTPUT)
           {
               auto test_case = FUNCTION_NAME(begin, end); 

               // DO SOME COMPARISON 

               // output error or success 
           }

           int test1([interator])
           { 
               int output = // do something;
               return output; 
           }

     protected:

}
```

So basically, I would pass in an iterator to the constructor, also a function which would carry out the test and also some expected output, this would then do some comparison and display the output.

Comment: What you are doing is similar to the google test framework, have a look

Comment: Are you looking for function pointer (or member function pointer or `std::function`) ?